# Style concatenation using conditional styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

Could you elaborate this expression written in React

```
<View style={[styles.button, this.state.touching && styles.highlight]} />
```

I know that Style attribute accepts an array of objects, what wonders me is the `this.state.touching && styles.highlight` part. Can someone enlighten me on how this works? Many thanks!

Comment: yes it is absolutely valid, what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to know how this && thingy works. As per @Ori Drori, this is called 'logical end'?

Comment: You can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) for some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [logical if](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510) using And (`&&`). If the first value is false, it will return that value, if it's truthy, it will return the 2nd value.

```js
const state = {
  touching: false
};

const styles = {
  highlight: 'highlightClass'
};

console.log('state.touching is false: ', state.touching && styles.highlight);

state.touching = true;

console.log('state.touching is true: ',state.touching && styles.highlight);
```

Note that that there won't be a style of `false` if it's falsey, because react native styles ignore falsy values. According to the [docs](http://The%20behavior%20is%20the%20same%20as%20Object.assign:%20in%20case%20of%20conflicting%20values,%20the%20one%20from%20the%20right-most%20element%20will%20have%20precedence%20and%20falsy%20values%20like%20false,%20undefined%20and%20null%20will%20be%20ignored.%20A%20common%20pattern%20is%20to%20conditionally%20add%20a%20style%20based%20on%20some%20condition.):

> The behavior is the same as Object.assign: in case of conflicting
>   values, the one from the right-most element will have precedence and
>   falsy values like false, undefined and null will be ignored. A common
>   pattern is to conditionally add a style based on some condition.

Comment: Is there a reference I can read related to 'logical end' and others?

Comment: Based on ReactNative documentation, it states that falsy values (false, null, undefined) are ignored. So I think, the snippet above is valid.